# Define an operator without Built-in Meanings containing a Power function

Tags: operators, built-in-symbols

I would like to define the following operator:

$$
\left[T^{(j_{1})}\otimes
U^{(j_{2})}\right]_{m}^{(j)}=\sum_{m_{1},m_{2}}\left\langle j_{1},m_{1};j_{2},m_{2}\big|j,m\right\rangle T_{m_{1}}^{j_{1}}U_{m_{2}}^{j_{2}}
$$

where $\left\langle j_{1},m_{1};j_{2},m_{2}\big|j,m\right\rangle$ is the known Clebsch-Gordan function:

```
ClebschGordan[{Subscript[j, 1],Subscript[m, 1]},{Subscript[j, 2],Subscript[m, 2]},{j,m}].
```

I know how to define, for example, a plain $2\otimes3$ operation as explained in [Operators without Built-in Meanings](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html) but I encounter problems when using the `Power` function in my new definition. What I tried was

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t_\), \((j_)\)]\[CircleTimes]
\*SuperscriptBox[\(u_\), \((k_)\)])\), \(m_\), \((L_)\)] := \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(p = \(-j\)\), \(j\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(q = \(-k\)\), \
\(k\)]ClebschGordan[{j, p}, {k, q}, {L, m}] 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(p\), \(j\)] 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(u\), \(q\), \(k\)]\)\)\)
```

and in LaTex form

$$
\left(t\_^{(j\_)}\otimes
u\_^{(k\_)}\right)_{m\_}^{(L\_)}=\sum_{p=-j}^{j}\sum_{q=-k}^{k}ClebschGordan[\{j,p\},\{k,q\},\{L,m\}] t_{p}^{j}u_{q}^{k}
$$

where non of these `Superscript`functions is suppose to serve as a `Power` function. But I get the error [SetDelayed::write: "Tag Power in `Subsuperscript[(t_^(j_)\[CircleTimes]u_^(k_)), m_, L_]` is Protected. "](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/General/write.html).
I also tried working with `UpValues`:

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \((j)\)]\[CircleTimes]
\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), \((k)\)])\), \(m\), \((L)\)] /: 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t_\), \((j_)\)]\[CircleTimes]
\*SuperscriptBox[\(u_\), \((k_)\)])\), \(m_\), \((L_)\)] := \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(p = \(-j\)\), \(j\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(q = \(-k\)\), \
\(k\)]ClebschGordan[{j, p}, {k, q}, {L, m}] 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(p\), \(j\)] 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(u\), \(q\), \(k\)]\)\)\)
```

and in Latex form:

$$
\left(t^{(j)}\otimes
u^{(k)}\right)_{m}^{(L)}/:\left(t\_^{(j\_)}\otimes
u\_^{(k\_)}\right)_{m\_}^{(L\_)}=\sum_{p=-j}^{j}\sum_{q=-k}^{k}ClebschGordan[\{j,p\},\{k,q\},\{L,m\}] t_{p}^{j}u_{q}^{k}
$$

but with no success. I get the error [TagSetDelayed::sym: "Argument `Subsuperscript[(t^(j)\[CircleTimes]u^(k)), m, L]` at position 1 is expected to be a symbol. "].

A possible solution is the following:

```
Unprotect@Power
Power[Subscript[CircleTimes[t_^(j_), u_^(k_)], m_], L_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(p = \(-j\)\), \(j\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(q = \(-k\)\), \
\(k\)]ClebschGordan[{j, p}, {k, q}, {L, m}] 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(p\), \(j\)] 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(u\), \(q\), \(k\)]\)\)
Protect@Power
```

The problem here is that in order for it to work I need to give up over my:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];
```

command, since with it `Subscript[CircleTimes[t_^(j_), u_^(k_)], m_]` turns to be an True `AtomQ` element and then the index `m_` will not be read as a variable.
Is there any way around this - Keeping the Symbolize function **and** keeping this definition?

Comment: Please, use the `InputForm` of your code as it is more readable.

Comment: I hope (not sure though) this helps. Please let me know if there is anything else I can improve as I am new to Mathematica and to asking questions here.

Comment: @noam Could you please do it like this: selet your code, then goto **Edit** menu -> **Copy As** -> **Input Text**, then paste into this post.

Comment: @Silvia I copied as you asked. Seems like I got back to square one. I wrote it in Latex form as well if that helps.

Comment: @noam Would you agree the answers linked by m_goldberg solved your problem?

Comment: @Silvia it is similar to what I found out (wrote an answer for it) but I still have some questions about it.

Comment: Then I suggest you reform your question to include the effort you tried with the methods in those answers, and more importantly, address the *still-have* questions, so this post will not be a duiplicate.